# Power Automate - Can't Find Triggers or Actions

Tags: power-automate

I'm learning more about Power Automate and one of the frustrating things that I've come across is when I'm following along with a online post or video and they say to add a specific action/trigger/operation and it's simply not there when I use the search option.

It's getting to the point where I think there's limitations the company set, my knowledge of the software, posts constantly renaming items without providing the default name or a combination. I don't see much on this topic so maybe a pro will help and others will learn.

Examples that I've come across:
Add the following trigger "When an Item or File is modified"

- When I press the + in Power Automate and type that in the search I get back nothing

Another is when I utilized a flow that MS provides and again has a item that when I later try to use for another flow and I search it, it never pulls up... I almost feel like I'm going crazy half the time.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're facing a context issue.  For example, you have cited clicking the "+" but not finding a trigger.  Since triggers are what "trigger" a flow, they are only automatically visible when you first create a flow or remove the existing trigger.  Searching for a trigger after one has been established will not return any results because the view defaults to Actions.  You can search for triggers after the fact by changing the view, but you cannot use them unless, as mentioned earlier, you remove the existing one.

I've had the opposite problem where actions are listed that my company is not licensed to use, yet.  Essentially finding more than is technically available, trial licenses notwithstanding.

In the attached examples you will see that in a net-new flow, I manually changed the context to "Actions."  If I try to select an action as the first object, I get an error because Power Automate expects a trigger.  The reciprocal is also true.  In the second example, if I try to select a trigger after one has been established, another error occurs.

[Action as Trigger Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0wwP.png)
[Trigger as Action Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egbU7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not searching through "Templates" instead of triggers?